# 2013 Calculating a column from 2 existing yes/No columns - FAILS SharePoint bug?

Tags: calculated-column-formula

Here is the requirement:

Col1 (Employee is PM?)
Col2 (Employee works at HQ?)
Col3 (Calculated Value)

Formula:  If both Col1 AND Col2 = "No", than Col3="No", Else Col3="Yes"

This SHOULD WORK:  `=IF(AND([Col1]="No",[Col2]="No"),"No","Yes")`

But every scenario the answers all come out to NO, no matter what the values of Col 1 & Col2 actually are.   Is this not even possible!?

Comment: What is the data type of Col1 and Col2? Are they Single line of text or Yes/No? Cuz the formula looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Yes/No, then the formula has to change a little bit to be:

```
=IF(AND([Col1]=0,[Col2]=0),"No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is very loosly typed so

- Empty Strings
- 0 values
- Empty Dates
- FALSE

are all False values

```
=IF(AND([Col1]=0,[Col2]=0),"No","Yes")
```

If this Formula outputs a Boolean

You are saying:

```
=IF(AND([Col1]=FALSE,[Col2]=FALSE),FALSE,TRUE)
```

You can take out the IF with:

```
=NOT(AND([Col1]=FALSE,[Col2]=FALSE))
```

And this the same Logic as:

```
=OR([Col1],[Col2])
```

Because:

```
OR ( F , F ) =  False
OR ( T , F ) =  True
OR ( F , T ) =  True
OR ( T , T ) =  True
```